# Android: onprepareoptionsmenu called after finish()

Tags: android

Background: I have an activity that needs to be customized based on some global variables kept in the application class. To make sure those variables are still available when my app is moved back to the foreground, I do some checks in `onResume()`. If everything is fine, it continues to set up actionbar, interface etc, otherwise, it sends the app to an activity that initializes the whole app (basically just restart) and calls `finish()` on this activity.

Problem: However, after calling `finish()`, while it does go to the other activity, it'd come back at some point to execute `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionMenu`, which will fail due to action on null object. This behavior befuddles me. Shouldn't `finish()` have finished the process on that activity? What else should I do to properly transfer to another activity?

P.S. Currently my workaround is to set a flag after `finish()` and check it in onCreateOptionMenu and onPrepareOptionMenu.

Comment: Old thread but did you find any other mechanism? Flag seems to be one hacky way but that works.